# How to scroll the scrollbar in external application via WinAPI?

Tags: winapi, scroll

**Description**

I'm trying to test application coded in Delphi (VCL components by DevEx) with TestComplete. Application is built without debug info.

I need to scroll TcxTreeList component. The problem is when I set `Position` property for this component's scrollbars content is not scrolled but scroll bar position changes. I tried a lot of approaches and suppose that WinAPI can help me.

**The Question:**

**How to scroll the scrollbar in external application via WinAPI?**

I found PostMessage function, but I do not know how to synthesize WM_SCROLL message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll one line down (you can see other constants at the page JustBoo mentions);

```
PostMessage(HWnd, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0)
```

Scroll to a specific position;

```
PostMessage(HWnd, WM_VSCROLL, MakeWParam(SB_THUMBPOSITION, 30), 0)
```

But if you refer to [this page](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/27697/95822.aspx) on the Devex forums, it is mentioned that 
`"ScrollBar in the cxTreeList it is another control, not standard windows scrollbar"`.
So it might not work. In this case you might want to try [ScrollWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787593%28VS.85%29.aspx) coupled with setting the position as you already do.